# IP Forwarding With Azure - After Decommissioning VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a Linux VM on Azure.  This VM has an External IP, let's call it VMIP.

I need to decommission the VM and move the traffic to a new External IP.

We have moved most of the traffic via a DNS CNAME chain but some clients have an A-Record direct to VMIP.

How can I:

(a) Save the VMIP as static

(b) Decommission the VM

(c) Set up forwarding of all Port 80 traffic on VMIP to an External IP

Comment: Do you want to create a new VM and use the original's IP address?

Comment: Is this the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve that with Azure, talking about number 3. What might help you is setting the IP as static and assigning it to another VM.

To assign static IP to a VM follow this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-deploy-static-pip-arm-portal

Comment: There is no way to have an IP address forward traffic, independently of a VM?

Comment: ok, so we have to (a) Save the VMIP as static (b) Decommission the VM (c) create a new VM (d) assign the static VMIP to the new VM.  Is that right?

Comment: yeah, only thing I can think of, unless you want to pay for a VM to just forward traffic

Comment: ok, thanks for your help.  Is there a method for assigning a static IP to a new VM?  Does MS have a walkthrough somewhere?  Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Have a lovely day   :D